# Which word is used incorrectly in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

I found the below Facebook post [shared on lamebook.com](http://www.lamebook.com/ummm-what/). The caption claims that some word is used with an incorrect meaning, and the title "Ummm, what?" also suggests the same. However, I couldn't find any word wrongly used after reading it several times. Could someone explain what I am missing here?

The sentence is:

> New addition to the family, Rosie, her hobbies include Netflix and chill and she enjoys Sunday walks and knitting.

[image: Picture from http://www.lamebook.com/ummm-what/]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not actually a case of a *word* being misused but a *meme*: in this case, "Netflix and chill".

It was originally coined as a description of sitting down after a long day and watching some Netflix, but has changed in meaning so it's now a euphemism for inviting someone over with the intention of casual sex.

What the poster is indicating is that saying a dog enjoys "Netflix and chill" is possibly not what the original poster intended.

Comment: A lot of people aren't: it's resulted in some pretty embarrassing posts, as you can see. :)

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer, but just one nitpick: the meme is the picture with the "you don't know it means" and the netflix and chill is the phrase which functions as an innuendo. The meme should say "You keep using that phrase...". The meme is using incorrect language. :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire "Netflix and Chill" is still a meme; memes don't have to be images. :) Thanks for the +1 though!

Comment: See the definition of meme: "an image, video, **piece of text**, etc., typically humorous in nature, that is copied and spread rapidly by Internet users, often with slight variations."

Comment: Yes yes, I know and you're right it can be text only. Just not sure if it's really a meme since the intent behind its original use was as you note was a clever way of suggesting casual sex, it's only humorous now when people don't know they're publicly asking for or saying they like casual sex using this phrase. :) lol

Comment: @TechnikEmpire It's a valid point: would you prefer that I edit so it says phrase instead?

Comment: @JohnClifford Nope, your answer do what you think is right. Was trying to clarify terms but the terms we're forced to use here are so loosely defined and broad that meme would actually fit I suppose. Drop the word "nitpick" from my original comment. :)

Comment: Actually, I wasn't even aware of the "correct"/original usage of Netflix and chill. Oh well, you learn something new everyday - and sometimes it is just not-so-useful trivia. ;-)

Comment: @JohnClifford I was very surprised to learn that the definition of *meme* wasn't strictly limited to imagery. In fact, I've found it so unexpected that I talked to some friends and the conclusion of that discussion is that we believe that the *piece of text* is supposed to be an image (written text, of course, but embedded as a part of a graphics not text). The rationale behind this is that such text's meaning might very well be coupled with properties such as color, font etc., meaning that pure text would loose its sense. We'd love to hear your comment on this.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I would consider any text which goes into heavy/popular use on the internet (or in society in general really) a meme by definition; I think if the piece of text were meant to be an image it wouldn't have been mentioned in the first place because image covers that too. Bear in mind that the concept of a meme was around before the internet was. That said, it's definitely an interesting discussion point and I respect that a lot of people won't share my opinion, so thanks for your comment.

Comment: @JohnClifford After a second round of discussion in our group, we've arrived at the conclusion that *meme* is today **seen** strictly as a picture **but** that it's a misconception that deviates from the **actual** definition and origin. A bit like *phone* today is de facto a smartphone and the original concept of it, à la Mr. Bell, has been ushered out by ignorance. So, we stand corrected - thanks for the info - keeping in mind many other will raise an eyebrows to *imageless meme*.

Comment: @KonradViltersten The word *meme* refers to a propagating idea, the idea equivalent of a gene. The idea of an internet meme is a subset of the broader concept, but I definitely don't think it's limited to images. The humorous images with text on them are called image macros.

Comment: @Paul Yes, I got that from John's comment. I meant, perhaps losing it in translation or due to my occasionally ironic way, to admit me (us) being mistaken and glad about learning that there's a broader meaning to the term. I stand (gladly) corrected as I've learned something new, just now.